# Restful security check for webpage menu items

Tags: python, rest, security, frontend, web-deployment

When I want to check that a user has no access to a specific menu item, I pass a value in my REST API like this:

```
{
menu_item1: false,
menu_item2: true
}
```

And regarding to these values, menu items will be visible/invisible.
Is it a security issue that a user which is not authorized can see a menu item, can see that item in page_source with invisible status? Do I have to render pages and item visibility server side?
Even if the user can see the menu item, he can not request the URL because of server side security checks,I want to have a single page web application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , since the item is part of the page DOM , all that you are doing is just making it invisible . There are numerous ways in which the client side page rendering be changed on the fly to make the item visible again. Ideally you should not send the menu Item in the  API return and do not add those items in the page DOM during rendering.

```
{
    menu_item2: true
}
```

Comment: what kind of security issue it can be? At most the user can see a menu, but when he wants to open that link, he can not do that because of the server security checks. I want to have a single page application

Comment: You did not mentioned that there are server side checks. In that case if there are server side checks as well .. Just showing them in disabled mode will not cause any security issues but it may become an User Experience Issue.